# Ilmenau Template Getting Rid of Header Section Circles and Other Manipulations

Tags: beamer, header-footer, templates

I would like to get rid of the ugly circles that indicate "How many slides are there in this section?" I also would like my next section to not appear until I actually come to the first slide of it. That is What I have is this

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty  %no navigation pane
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{} %to remove slide numbers
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{} %To remove page numbers



\begin{document}


\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Curent Version]

But what I want is this (Assume same presentation with two sections, section 2 to appear later on.)

[image: Desired version]

Also, if we can get rid of the extra space on the red header due to removed circles, that would be perfect.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a new defined `headline` you get the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty 
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
   \hspace{3ex}{\insertsectionhead}
 \end{beamercolorbox}
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
 \end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}


\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```